# Correct syntax to use class functions on an instance in a node? c++

Tags: c++, syntax, linked-list, nodes

I'm writing a linked list to manage an simple inventory for an rpg. I have a class called `inventory` and a class called `item`. My program only makes one inventory and adds and deletes items from it. Each instance of `item` contains a name (`char*`) and a weight (`double`). name and weight are private members of `item`.

I wrote two functions to return the values of name and weight in `item.h`, `GetWeight()` and `GetName()`. When I call them directly on an item they work just fine (for example, `Item.GetName()` ). However, when I try to call them on an instance of item IN a node, they return void and the program crashes. (example: I have a pointer called `cur` that points to a node containing an instance of item and I write `cur->ItemInstance.GetName()` ). I have examined my syntax and everything else I could think of and don't understand what could be leading to this error.

Here is item.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

class item
{
public:

    item();
    item(const item& Item);
    item(char * name, double weight);

    virtual ~item(void); // destructor

    char *GetName() { return this->name; } ;
    double GetWeight() { return weight; }

private:
    char *name;     // name of the item
    double weight;  // keeps track of weight of that/those item(s)

};

#endif
```

and here is inventory.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include "item.h"

class inventory
{
public:
    inventory(void);          // Constructor
    virtual ~inventory(void); // destructor
    inventory(int);
    // Public Methods:

    // Adds Item:
    bool AddItem(item Item);

    // RemoveItem();
    bool RemoveItem(char * name);

    // GetCount(); and GetWeight(); 
    const int GetTotalCount() const { return TotalCount; } 

    const double GetTotalWeight() const { return TotalWeight; }

    // Prints the inventory
    void PrintInventory();

private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node(item Item);                // constructor
        item ItemInstance;                  // an instance of Item
        Node *next;                         // next node in the item thread
        int count;                          // count of that particular item        
    };
    Node      *head;
    double    TotalWeight;                  // keeps track of weight being carried
    int       TotalCount;                   // keeps track of total # of items
    const int MaxWeight;

};
#endif
```

The program keeps crashing in `inventory.cpp`, where my `AddItem` function is, while trying to add the second item to the list.

The line it crashes at is:

```
if (strcmp(ToLowerName, cur->ItemInstance.GetName()) == 0)
```

Note that `node* head` points to the first node in the list and `node* cur = head`. `ToLowerName` is a lowered copy of the name of the new item I'm trying to insert. This line is the first of its kind that the program hits when it runs, which is trying to check for identical entries.

As I said, anytime an item is directly referenced (as in, `Item.GetName()` ), the function has worked perfectly. However, the debugger shows the value of `cur->ItemInstance.GetName()` and `cur->ItemInstance.GetWeight()` both as being `void`.

I put a watch on everything in the debugger, and everything contains the information it's supposed to (`head`, `ToLowerName`, `cur`, `cur->ItemInstance`, etc.), so I know that I've isolated the problem, I just don't know why the functions won't return correctly.

Thanks for the help and I apologize if this was too long, I wanted to make sure I was providing enough information. If anything more is needed please let me know

edit: here is everything in inventory.cpp that I think is relevant (I'm not bothering to include the removeitem function because it's very similar and the program hasn't even gotten to it yet)

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)   
#include <iostream>
#include "inventory.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



using namespace std;

inventory::inventory() :
MaxWeight(100),
head(NULL),
TotalWeight(0),
TotalCount(0)
{
}

inventory::~inventory()

// I'm not sure this destructor is perfect, need to double check it

{
    Node *node(head);
    Node *nextNode;

    while (node)
    {
        nextNode = node->next;
        delete     node;
        node = nextNode;
    }
}

// constructor
inventory::Node::Node(item ItemConst) :
next(NULL),
ItemInstance(ItemConst.GetName(), ItemConst.GetWeight()),
count(0)
{
}

// constructor for bad data section 
inventory::inventory(int InvWeight) :
MaxWeight(InvWeight),
head(NULL),
TotalWeight(0),
TotalCount(0)
{

}

// not including the print inventory function for stackoverflow

bool inventory::AddItem(item Item)
{

    // TempName stores an exact copy of the name passed in

    int StringLength = strlen(Item.GetName());
    StringLength = StringLength + 1;
    char * TempName = new char[StringLength + 1];
    strcpy(TempName, Item.GetName());

    // tempweight is a copy of the weight passed in

    double TempWeight = Item.GetWeight();

    // ToLowerName stores a 'tolower'd copy of the name passed in

    char * ToLowerName = new char[StringLength + 1];   // Set aside enough space for string and null character.
    for (int i = 0; i < StringLength; i++){  // Loop over characters in string and no further.
        ToLowerName[i] = tolower(TempName[i]);    // Copy characters over in lowercase as we loop.
        }
    ToLowerName[StringLength] = '\0';

    // I'm creating a new node and putting the info passed in into it
    Node *newNode = new Node(item(ToLowerName, TempWeight));
    Node * cur = head;
    Node * previous = NULL;

// Adding item if list is empty (note: this part works)
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->count++;
        TotalWeight = TotalWeight + TempWeight;
        cout << "You picked up a " << TempName << "." << endl << endl;
        TotalCount++;
        return true;
    }

    // Adding new item if list is NOT empty
    if (head != NULL)
    {
    //iterate through list
    //for loop keeps looping until it's totaled the number of items added to the list
        for(int i = 0; i < this->GetTotalCount(); i++)
        {

        // duplicate item

            if (strcmp(ToLowerName, cur->ItemInstance.GetName()) == 0)
            {
                if (newNode->ItemInstance.GetWeight() != cur->ItemInstance.GetWeight())
                {
                    cout << "ERROR: tried to add a duplicate item with wrong weight!" << endl << endl;
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You picked up a " << TempName << "." << endl << endl;
                    cur->count++;
                    TotalWeight = TotalWeight + TempWeight;
                    TotalCount++;
                    delete cur;
                    cur = NULL;
                    return true;
                }

            }

        // deleted functions for adding to front middle and end of list for stackoverflow , don't believe they are relevant

        previous = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Also please note that the item I'm adding and the item I'm comparing it to (ToLowerName and cur->ItemInstance.GetName() do not have the same name, so the code inside the if statements won't actually run. The problem is that the program is returning void for cur->ItemInstance.GetName() and cur->ItemInstance.GetWeight(), so it fails when it tries to evaluate the strcmp line.

Comment: That all looks mostly OK, so the bug is probably within inventory.cpp. Can you post the relevant parts?

Comment: I added the parts of inventory.cpp that I think are relevant. I hope it's not too long, thanks so much for looking

Comment: I added a note of it but i should mention, the item that I'm adding does not have the same name as the only other item thus in the list, so the whole duplicate statement won't actually run. the program breaks when it tries to run the strcmp statement and cur->ItemInstance.GetName() is considered void